# App with FINE_LOCATION installed on devices without GPS?

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

My GPS app started installing on devices that don't have GPS hardware such as the Pixel C. I specifically require GPS level accuracy for my app.

My `build.gradle` file looks like

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.application.id"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
  }
}
```

How can I ensure that my app is only installed on with GPS hardware? What changed that this is happening to my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted on the [`<uses-feature>` page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions-features), `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` no longer implies the `android.hardware.location.gps` feature if you target API 21 or higher.

While in most cases this won't be an issue since Wi-Fi and Cell-ID is accurate enough, if you really need GPS hardware (such as if you are a GPS navigation app or fitness app), you can explicitly add

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

As noted on that same page, `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` was also changed to not require the `android.hardware.location.network` feature either.